# Infinite loop with Google Maps JS API place details call "open_now"

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API to get Place Details. As of yesterday, I've been getting this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object._.Xm (common.js:1)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
    at Object.get [as open_now] (util.js:213)
```

My code (in Typescript) is:

```
async function getGooglePlaceDetails(placeId: string, sessionToken?: string) {
  const googleMapsClient = createClient({
    key: config.googleMapsServerAPIKey,
    Promise,
  });

  const response = await googleMapsClient
    .place({ placeid: placeId, sessiontoken: sessionToken })
    .asPromise();

  return response;
}
```

This fails for certain places like `ChIJ71yZMAvSCl8RY1u0MpwXJXA` ("Houheikyou hot springs").

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has recently been fixed. This was also reported in Google's Public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137213536

The issue was due to the recent Maps JavaScript API version 3.37 rollover which was already fixed by Google engineers as per the public bug.

Please note that switching to the older versions is a temporary workaround, and will no longer work once the older versions are fully deprecated. If the error with the new version is still reproducible on your end, you can comment on the issue link above for the engineers to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the `util.js` included in version 37. You can fix this by changing your Google Maps API version string to `v=quarterly` or 36.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key=...&libraries=geometry,drawing,places

(replace those libraries with your own)

For more details, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Comment: You should check the issue tracker for an existing bug or file your own if you don't find one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853